# Calling other classes from Main in C#

Tags: c#

Have two questions assigned for homework, both of the same form, so I'll post the first one:

"Create  an  Employee  class.  Items  to  include  as  data  members  are
employee number, name, date of hire, job description, department, and
monthly salary. The class is often used to display an alphabetical listing of all employees. Include appropriate constructors and properties. Override the
ToString ( ) method to return all data members. Create a second class
to test your Employee class."

I've created an Employee class with the proper variables, properties, and constructors, but am having trouble "testing" it through a second class. The code I have written runs without errors, but doesn't display anything (presumably the goal of the testing). Where am I going wrong in the calling section?

Employee info section:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeProgram
{
    public class employee
    {
        private int employeeNumber;
        private string name;
        private string hiredate;
        private int monthlySalary;
        private string description;
        private string department;

    public employee(int employeeNumber, string name, string dateOfHire, int monthlySalary, string description, string department)
    {

        this.employeeNumber = 321;
        this.name = "Alex";
        this.hiredate = "01/02/15";
        this.monthlySalary = 2500;
        this.description = "Corporate grunt";
        this.department = "Sales";
    }

    public int EmployeeNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Hiredate
    {
        get
        {
            return hiredate;
        }
        set
        {
            hiredate = value;
        }
    }

    public int MonthlySalary
    {
        get
        {
            return monthlySalary;
        }
        set
        {
            monthlySalary = value;
        }
    }
    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            return department;
        }
        set
        {
            department = value;
        }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee ID: " + employeeNumber +
               "Employee Name: " + name +
               "Employee Hire Date: " + hiredate +
               "Employee Monthly Salary: " + monthlySalary +
               "Employee Description: " + description +
               "Employee Department: " + department;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
    }
}
```

"Calling section"

```
namespace employee
{
    public class employeeApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            EmployeeProgram.employee Employee = new EmployeeProgram.employee(321, "Alex", "1/02/15", 2500, "Corporate grunt", "Sales");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the print method.....?

Comment: You create an instance of `Employee`, but you never do anything with it. Presumably, you want to display it on the console. That you've overrideen the `ToString` method is a hint for how to do so, your teacher also likely introduced the `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` methods to you in class. As a side note, under normal C# naming conventions class names should be capitalized, i.e. your class named `employee` *should* be named `Employee`. This may not seem important now, but not following standard conventions is a sure fire way to make your code unreadable.

Comment: you are not calling Employee.Print which is what prints out the employee.

Comment: I should be calling the print method (what I have at the bottom of the employee section) in the main page instead?

Comment: As an aside, you could reduce the amount of boilerplate you're writing by using auto-implemented properties (ex: `public string Description { get; private set; }`

Comment: Got it working (pending spacing issues). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the `Print()` method of `EmployeeProgram.employee` in the `main()` method.

```
namespace employee
{
    public class employeeApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            EmployeeProgram.employee Employee = new EmployeeProgram.employee(321, "Alex", "1/02/15", 2500, "Corporate grunt", "Sales");
            Employee.Print();
        }

    }
}
```

But as others have pointed out, there are a lot of issues with your code:

- Class name should be in Pascal casing, i.e., start with a capital letter. Hence, it should be `EmployeeProgram.Employee` and not `EmployeeProgram.employee`
- Private variables generally follow Camel casing, i.e., start with small letter. Hence, it should be `meployee` instead of `Employee` in your `Main()` method.
- You can reduce the boilerplate code in your `employee` class by making use to auto-properties.
- Parameter `dateOfHire` should be a `DateTime` object instead of `string`.
- Parameters like `monthlySalary` are generally of type `decimal` and not `int`.